# Reading binary file in string shows strange output

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles, fread

So, here is my scenario:

I have a binary file, and the information I got is: file size is 1kb, there are only chars in the file, and file is binary.

So, I tried to read and print first 128 chars to test doing like this:

```
FILE *f;
if((f = fopen(argv[1],"rb")) == NULL){ 
    printf("CANNOT OPEN FILE\n");
    exit(1);
}

char buffer[128];
printf("%d\n",fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 128, f));
printf("%s", buffer);
```

But the output does not look as a 128 size-long string at all, the output is this:
�1X�Z%]X�^ԫ��ƛ�T�tA!=܇p�>�A��g>~���k�*��;�2�

Does anyone know what my mistake was?

Comment: What does the file contain? Have you tried opening it in Notepad?

Comment: I assume the printout of the return value from `fread` shows 128 and nothing else? (It might not work, since `fread` returns a `size_t`, which is not necessarily the same as an `int`.) Also, since `buffer` isn't NUL-terminated, you might see garbage being printed. Try this: `printf("%128s", buffer);`

Comment: @immibis the file is binary

Comment: When you use `printf()`, it treats the buffer as a NUL-terminated string. It looks like a NUL character occurred way before the 128th byte, so you got a relatively short string printed.

Comment: The file is binary? Ok, that probably explains it. Binary data usually looks like garbage if you try to pretend it is text.

Comment: Your question seems a little contradictionary. You say you have a *binary* file, but you treat the data you read as text, which it most likely isn't.

Comment: If the question is just about why the string of garbage is so short, and not why it looks like garbage instead of text, then Nayuki Minase's comment is probably the correct answer.

Comment: The reason why I am trying the read as text, is that I am 100% sure that content written was chars, but it is binary, so I can't manage this data?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the content written was chars, but it is binary"?

Comment: If you paste the output of `od -c filename | head -4`, we can help you make sense of the file. It might have been written as 16-bit-wide characters, for instance, so using the `char` type and the `%s` format might not be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your file contains non-ASCII characters, the result will look like garbage.
2. If your read failed, then the buffer will be uninitialized, and the result will look like garbage.
3. If there is no "NULL" terminator, then some - or all - of your output will look like garbage.
4. Even if the buffer prints garbage - and there is a NULL character - the output will end at '\0'.

SUGGESTION:

Look at the file in notepad.  Or, even better, look at it in a hex editor.

Linux has a ["strings"](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) command that will print only the text strings in a binary file.  You can download a Windows version of "strings" here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/strings.aspx

Answer (score 1):

After you read data into buffer, try to print the ASCII codes of the characters. That will indicate whether the characters are printable or not.

```
char buffer[128];
int n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 128, f);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
   printf("i: %d, ASCII code: %d\n", i, buffer[i]);
}
```